# Playing Audio Files in Android Logs Strange Error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using this method to play sounds in my assets

```
public void PlaySound(String sound_name) {
    try {

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.stop();
            }
            mPlayer.release();
        }
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        int timerSoundId;
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        timerSoundId = getResources().getIdentifier( sound_name , "raw" , packageName );


        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getResources().openRawResourceFd(timerSoundId);
        mPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        mPlayer.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

while I test the application on the device, whenever sound is played this error is printed

```
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyService: getOutput() tid 6093 ++
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyService: getOutput() tid 6093 --
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyService: getOutput() tid 6093 ++
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyService: getOutput() tid 6093 --
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyService: getOutput() tid 6093 ++
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyService: getOutput() tid 6093 --
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyService: getOutput() tid 6093 ++
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyService: getOutput() tid 6093 --
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: unknown stream type
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: unknown stream type
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: unknown stream type
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: unknown stream type
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: unknown stream type
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: unknown stream type
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: unknown stream type
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: unknown stream type
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: unknown stream type
07-19 11:21:55.715    1833-6093/? E/AudioPolicyManagerBase: unknown stream type
```

App does not crash and I could not detect any problem. I thought the reason would be the format of the Audio files. They were wav. but then I changed them to mp3, still no difference. Music plays but leaves these Log lines behind it.

Do I have to worry about it? Or just ignore it?
Any suggestion would be appreciated...